# How to redelegate with JS Nami/Eternl wallets?

Tags: staking

Could you please point how can I **unstake/undelegate** OR **redelegate** with web cardano (`window.cardano`) api?

I need to let users delegate to my pool even if they already delegated anywhere else, so I need to track if the user already delegated - if the user did -> unstake and delegate to my pool.

I succeed doing that will Typhon (i was just creating a new transaction for delegate), but the Nami/Eternl doesn't seem to work

Nami (doesn't work): opens the wallet popup and wants to get the full pool price and if I agree - it will fail signing the transaction

Typhon (works perfectly): opens the wallet popup and wants to get the difference between pool price + fee - the transaction signing works